# How to determine if there's access to the Exchange Admin Center as a user?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, administrator, exchange, multiple-users

Just looking to disable read receipts in Outlook.

AI says:

```
Copilot
To disable read receipts from portal.office.com email settings, you can follow these steps:
1.  Sign into your Office admin account via portal.office.com1.
2.  Navigate to the Exchange admin center.
3.  On the left pane, scroll down and click More features.
4.  Click open under Permissions and navigate to Mail Flow > Rules.
5.  Click + Add and select Modify messages.
6.  Enter a name for the rule, such as ‘Disable Read Receipt’.
Please note that these steps are for disabling read receipts for all accounts from the Exchange admin center2. If you want to disable read receipts for a specific account, the settings might be different. For example, in Outlook 2013, you can go to File > Options > Mail and scroll down to the Tracking section to manage read receipts34.
```

But I can't find the EAC and can only **infer that I don't have access**.

An image search shows a very different interface than what I see in my portal.  Is it a correct understanding that users won't always have access to the EAC for disabling read receipts?

Comment: Are you an Administrator? If you are not then there isn’t an answer to your question as it’s currently written. You should [edit] your question and remove any references to ChatGPT or Copilot as responses are not applicable to your situation

Answer (score 0):

(This is advice is useless - do not trust AI answers, they are many times
just nonsense.)

To disable read receipts in Outlook :

- Open Outlook and click *File > Options*
- Click *Mail*
- Within the Tracking section, click "Never send a read receipt"
- Click *Save*.

Comment: Agree with harrymc, you just need to turn off this option in the Outlook client without visiting the admin center.

Comment: I'm only on portal.office.com however and not seeing such an option.  This email account might not work with Outlook -- I'll have to check that out.